# Fragment view (swipeable menu) and ViewPager for Screen Sliding (Android developing)

Tags: menu, android-viewpager, sliding

I'm some how new to Android Programing.
I've written an app with Swipeable menu (With Fragment view) and also One of the tab should has Sliding Screen to show some texts.

I'm just puzzled in process. If someone can tell me the how to do it or some tutorial , It'd be helpful

Thanks in advance